# Is there a string-based array in java?

Tags: java

I can't find anywhere if there's some kind of collection where i can get items with:

```java
SpecialArray specialArray = new SpecialArray()
specialArray.put("first", someValue);
specialArray.put("second", otherValue);

//and then:
object obj = specialArray["first"];
//or:
specialArray["second"] = anotherValue;
```

It's a little like `HashMap<String, object>` but in a HashMap i can only 
get a value with `map.get(String)` update a value with `map.put(String, object)`

Comment: So you want to access this collection with `[]`, but also with a string inside? That's not possible in Java.

Comment: [] syntax for such cases are not available in Java, but you can have it in Kotlin Groovy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscripting using `<array-reference-expression> [ <expression> ]` in Java is only available for genuine array objects.  As [JLS 15.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) says:

> *"The type of the array reference expression must be an array type (call it `T[]`, an array whose components are of type `T`), or a compile-time error occurs.*

That's it.  No exceptions, workarounds or clever hacks.

Answer (score 2):

No, this syntax is not available in Java. You can get the functionality from `Map` using a different syntax.

If this is not enough, use another language.